# Changing Icon at run time in pagerslidingtabstrip

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using  Pagerslidingtabstrip library. I am aware that state drawable can be used for the tab selected and unselected property. I have a listview in my first fragment. As I scroll my listview at a particular moment I have to change the pagertab icon state drawable for that fragment. That means I have show a new state drawable. But I am not able to do it. Please Help!!

Comment: post your `Pagerslidingtabstrip` address.

Comment: Sry found out the answer ..just calling notifydatasetchanged for the tabs did the job :).. Thanks anyways..